Digit after null terminator in C?
TLDR: stuff like
char x[] = "some output \06 MORE OUTPUT";
puts(x);

gives unexpected results.
So I have this code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char x[] = "some output \0 MORE OUTPUT";
    puts(x);

    return 0;
}

And it prints: "some output", which is expected, because \0 means the end of the string. But if I add a digit just after the \0, the result changes. So the code
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char x[] = "some output \06 MORE OUTPUT";
    puts(x);

    return 0;
}

prints: some output ♠ MORE OUTPUT
So for some reason, if I add a number after \0, then \0 is no more recognized as the end of the string, and instead it prints this ♠ symbol.
If I just replace \0 with \6, the result is the same. If I do it with some other digits, the result is the same, except the symbol is different.
why is that? What is this \6 thing? I can't find anything about it online. How does it work?

Please read about "Escape Sequences".

In a nutshell, \06 ≠ \0\6!

(or \0006/\x006, which I think is what you meant.)

Also vaguely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704440/escape-sequence-in-c which is specifically about C, not C++

It means your terminal is using the antique DOS character set. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

@Ry Hex escape sequences do not automatically terminate after two hex digits, unlike octal escape sequences that do automatically terminate after three octal digits. "\0006" contains a null terminator followed by the digit 6, but "\x006" just contains the ASCII ACK character (ASCII code 6).

\0 actually has no special meaning other than a zero character. By convention, we write null terminators using that form since it makes the syntax resemble other escape sequences like \n.
But \ <digits> is actually a so-called octal escape sequence. Anything starting with \ will insert character into the string corresponding to an octal number. 06 being ACK or some such in ASCII, a non-printable character. \101 will print an 'A' and so on.
Where the escape sequence ends isn't really that well-defined in C, the compiler may keep on reading any digits following \ for as long as they can be used to form valid character. Or until it spots another escape sequence or the end of the string literal. In case of octal escape sequences, at most 3 digits are allowed (but there's also hex escape sequences \x which holds no upper limit of digits).
So \08 will for example result in a null terminator because the digit 8 cannot be part of an octal number. And \101666 will print A666 since no more than 3 valid octal digits are allowed.
To insert the character '6' after a null terminator or other octal escape sequence, the easiest is just to end the string literal:
char x[] = "some output \0" "6 MORE OUTPUT"; // string literals will get concatenated into one
puts(x);
char* secret_message = x + 13;
puts(secret_message);

Output:
some output 
6 MORE OUTPUT


"Where the escape sequence ends isn't really well-defined in C". An octal escape sequence has at most 3 octal digits, so "\0112" would be the same as "\t2" rather than "J" in ASCII.

\0 and \<digits> are indistinguishable. That's the point. Not that "\0 actually has no special meaning", which is itself meaningless.

@IanAbbott Ah yeah that seems to be the case, I must be mixing it up with hex escape sequences.

Not only does an octal escape have at most 3 digits (C17 6.4.4.4/1), but it has the longest digit sequence that can constitute an octal escape (C17 6.4.4.4/7). So, pretty well defined after all.  (Note: those references are to the section on character constants, but section 6.4.5 on string literals refers to the same provisions by using the same escape-sequence production in its formal grammar).

\NNN (where N is an integer between 0 and 7) in a string literal represents a single byte whose octal representation is NNN.  There may be 1, 2, or 3 digits after the \.  The \0 in the string literal is interpreted by the compiler as a byte with all 0 bits, while the \06 is interpreted as a byte with 2 bits set. (0000 0110).  The symbols that you see in the output are just the glyphs that your terminal is using to represent those bytes.

It would be clearer to say "a \0 not immediately followed by another octal digit is interpreted by the compiler as a byte with all 0 bits".  It might also help to observe that \00 and \000 mean the same thing under the same circumstances, and \000 even when it is followed by another digit.
